# How to rename a jar file inside another jar file?

Tags: jar

I have jar `foo.jar` which contains jar `foo/config/baar-temp.jar`.

What is the best method to rename `baar-temp.jar` to `baar.jar`?

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not part of your build process or anything like that? Just a `jar` file as input, `jar` file as output?

Comment: Wait. A jar file isn't a file system... :) You could try to extract the `baar-temp.jar`, rename it and than repackage it.

Comment: yes :) that is correct

Comment: how to repack? any steps?

Comment: There is a documentation on how to create jar files: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, jar format is based on zip and can be operated on as a file system using for example [ZipFileSystemProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) available in Java7. That allows us to do a rather simple manipulation with the insides of one:

```
private void renameStuffInsideJar(String jarFilePath){
    URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:"+jarFilePath);
    try {
        FileSystem jarFile = FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri)) {
        Path pathInJarfile = jarFile.getPath("foo/config/baar-temp.jar");
        Files.move(pathInZipfile,pathInZipfile.resolveSibling("baar.jar"));
    } catch(IOException e){
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if it's not code you want, you could just open your jar file in your preferred archive manager like 7zip or WinRar and rename it using that.

Comment: Actually, it is a file format. You are right, it is based on the ZIP format and you could use those tools to package and extract jars, but a format isn't equal to a system!

Comment: @TheRealVira Well, it is a file format, I concede that it's not a file system in the same way say, FAT32 is, but when you have tools that allow you to mount and use your file in said format as a file system I wouldn't say that calling it as such is a big error

Comment: @Deltgaris I know that it is tempting, but a half true answer is as good as none. ;)

Comment: @TheRealVira All right, let's be technically correct than, edited

Comment: plus one for being technical on Stack Overflow :P